# How does one go about building Alien Swarm?

Tags: open-source, valve

Valve just released Alien Swarm on steam, along with all the source code. I would love to build a version of it on my own machine and play a little bit with the code.

Has anyone here tried to build it yet? Is it easy enough to just build and run it?

Thanks.

Comment: I wish I could downlaod alien-sward :( my internet suck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic answer is that you first have to grab the Alien Swarm SDK. It should be a choice in the "tools" menu of your steam client. Download it, it's not very big. Then run it.

One of the options is "Create a mod". This extracts the source code to a useful location for you and sets up some config options. The help guide from that menu has info on how to compile and test it. Or you can view the info on the [valve developer wiki](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Swarm_SDK_Create_a_Mod). It's setup for visual studio 2005, but I was able to build it correctly with my copy of Visual Studio 2008. Seems pretty well set up for immediate modding.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Ben's answer, a bit of extra work is required to get it building in Visual Studio 2010.  For the client project, you need to either change the name of the project from the default "Client (Swarm)" to just "client", or change the Target Name property to "client" from the default "$(ProjectName)".  After this, it builds without a hitch.

Comment: Delta, thank you for your help. I am using VS 2010, and it all worked after renaming. Unfortunately, I can't accept two answers! :)